# Creating zombie Process in C

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, fork, zombie-process

I am trying to create a zombie process in C do the following:

1 - creating child process

2 - let the parent wait/sleep for 60s

3 - child process ends after creating it immediately.

And i want to show details in console about the process and its usage of CPU for example.

i wrote the following code but i see nothing running in console with this command  `ps -l`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{

    int pid = fork();

    // Parent process
    if (pid > 0)
        sleep(60);

    // Child process
    else {
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Roi — `pid` will be zero in the child process.  It may be negative if the `fork()` fails.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- Oh that's true. I was confused with `pidof`. Sorry OP.

Comment: consider adding `else if (pid < 0) { perror("fork"); exit(1); }` to your if-else. Probably not relevant here, but a good practice.